# What's the deal with Hank Hill's wall clock on King of the Hill?

Tags: king-of-the-hill

I've noticed that this clock seems to randomly change color a lot. Not when you're looking right at it, but between scenes and episodes. I've definitely seen it be brown (like I would expect) and also this bluish purple.

Is it really a color-changing clock? Or what's the deal here?

[image]

It doesn't seem to fit the Hill family's personality to have a hippie color-changing clock. This is what I would've expected it to be:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that it's simply an animation error, like the ones that inspired [these rules](http://imgur.com/a/PiJLk).

Comment: Idk b/c it happened so often (almost every episode) but still +1 for the awesome link. Really cool!

Answer (score 3):

Although we can't be positive, it's very unlikely that this was intended and not just a error.  Things like this happen pretty often in animation, especially older animation.

You may have also noticed that the Hill's house switches between several different blueprints throughout the series.  The layout of the furniture also changes.  Although, I haven't noticed it between scenes like the clock.